# Acompanhamento de vizualização (pop up)

Tags: php, javascript, html5, microsoft-excel, popup

Olá,

Estou com uma duvida sobre HTML, preciso controlar quantas vezes um pop up é aberto, ele está programado para abrir toda vez que um computador inicia.

Preciso jogar esse dado para um excel (devido as diretrizes do local de trabalho), toda vez que ele abrir no computador, o excel recebe um aviso e adiciona +1 na tabela, porém, não sei se é possível. Alguém sabe se existe alguma solução em PHP ou JavaScript?

Comment: É um popup html ou um popup janela do navegador ?

Comment: É em HTML mesmo.

Comment: Coloca na pergunta o código que faz a chamada dessa popup, pra saber como você inicia ela, ai da pra dizer como fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei que popup está dizendo, se é algum modal ou se é um alert, mas seria algo simples fazer a verificação. Outra coisa que não entendi é:

> ele está programado para abrir toda vez que um computador inicia.

Isso quer dizer o que? Que o popup não é na web? Não entendi direito.

A verificação ficaria algo assim:

```
$PopupAbriu = 0;
function PopupAbrir(){
   //Aqui o que mais a função vai fazer
   $PopupAbriu += 1;
}
```

Depois você toda vez que o sistema iniciar, você vai ter que inicar essa função também, com o `PopupAbrir()`. Mas, como eu disse, ficou meio em aberto o que realmente você quer.

Abs;